# Transformation of uncertainty intervals - how to log transform SE and 95% conf interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, estimation, inference, data-transformation

A question from Gelman;

'On page 15 there is a discussion of an experimental study of an education-related intervention in Jamaica. The point estimate of the multiplicative effect is 1.42 with a 95% confidence interval of [1.02, 1.98], on a scale for which 1.0 corresponds to a multiplying by 1, or no effect. Reconstruct the reasoning by which this is a symmetric interval on the log scale:

(a) What is the point estimate on the logarithmic scale? That is, what is the point estimate of the treatment effect on log earnings?

(b) What is the standard error on the logarithmic scale?'

This question is related to another question I am working on, which requires the correct values from this question, which I cannot seem to get right. I believe the mistake is coming from not correctly understanding the task presented here.

I'm a little confused on how to convert this information to log scale - it seems it would be a little more complicated than simply taking logs. My thinking is that if we know the estimate and 95% interval then we can get the SE by;

1.98 = 1.42 + 1.96*SE

SE = .56/1.96 = .28

Estimate = 1.42

I don't understand how then I transform these values correctly onto a log scale other than simply just taking the log of each value. The reason I believe it is wrong is because when I use the SE value to simulate data, I get NaNs.

```
rnorm(100, log(1.42), log(.23))

[1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [30] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [59] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [88] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Warning message:
In rnorm(100, est, se) : NAs produced
```

Generating a normal distribution using Estimate and SE, taking logs, and calculating the mean and se does not yield the correct answers either.

Comment: Are you aware that (natural) logarithms of numbers less than $1,$ such as $0.23,$ are *negative?*  A review of logarithms might be a good first step.

Comment: Yes, I know they are negative. I know the SE value is incorrect, I am just not sure how to calculate the correct one for this case.

Comment: Okay, then a tiny hint should get you rolling: compare $1.98/1.42$ to $1.42/1.02.$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately, it is a little too small for me at the moment. I can see they are approximately equal ratios but I'm not sure what to do with it and find myself going in circles. I think I am supposed to do something with the linear transformation relationship UB.new = a + b*UB.old ?

Comment: "On a logarithmic scale" means to take the logarithms of anything measured in the same units as the actual data values.  Thus, on a log scale the three key statistics $(1.02, 1.42, 1.98)$ become $(0.02, 0.35, 0.68).$ The question asks you to (a) show this is a symmetric interval and (b) back out the SE (by understanding how the SE is used to compute confidence limits).

Comment: Ah yes, this seems fairly obvious now. I knew this was a simple task, but I guess my lack of familiarity with some of the concepts prevents me from clearly seeing what is required to complete the question. Thank you for the help!

Comment: By the way, what do I do if a question has been answered via the comments? Just leave as is?